# Printing value in void to other void

Tags: c++

I'm trying to print a value found in the "getvalue" void in the "show" void. I get an error:

error: 'Students' was not declared in this scope

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int studentNumber=0;
int testNumber=0;
struct Student
{
string name,grade;
int studentNo,*testResults;
double average;
};

void getValue()
{
    cout << "Enter the number of students: ";
    cin >> studentNumber;
    cout << "Enter the number of tests: ";
    cin >> testNumber;

    Student* Students = new Student[studentNumber];

    for(int i=0; i< studentNumber; i++)
    {
        cout<< "\n" << "Enter the name of the " << i+1 << ". student: ";
        cin >> Students[i].name;
        cout<< "\n" << "Enter the number of the " <<  i+1 << ". student: ";
        cin >> Students[i].studentNo;

        Students[i].testResults = new int[testNumber];

            for(int z=0; z<testNumber; z++)
            {
                cout<< "\n" << "Enter the " << z+1 << ". exam grade of the " << i+1 << ". student: " ;
                cin >> Students[i].testResults[z];
            }
    }
}

void show()
{
    for(int i=0; i < studentNumber; i++)
    {
        cout<< "\n" << Students[i].name;
        cout<< "\n" << Students[i].studentNo;
        for(int z=0; z<testNumber; z++)
            {
                cout<< "\n" <<Students[i].testResults[z];
            }
    }
}

int main()
{
    getValue();
    show();
}
```

I'm trying to show the obtained values ​​in another void called "show" but failed. (The general structure of the code that must be in a different void must be another void named "show" in my homework)

Comment: You should learn how to 1) pass function arguments and 2) return values from functions. In this case `getValue` could return a `std::vector<Student>` that can be passed as an argument to `show`

Comment: Welcome! Because this is homework I'll give you some tangential pointers that will make your code more readable (and potentially easier to debug/get help from this site!).

1) I try to avoid `namespace std` as it's typical in C++ dev to use the standard library (so the `std::` doesn't distract, at least for me)
2) Instead of a raw pointer I highly recommend a built-in smart pointer of some type, unless you have a very specific reason for the raw pointer. Even if you've that reason, write your code using standard lib smart ptrs and refactor (using the raw ptr) once working w/tests.

Comment: Your question would be much clearer if you didn't use "void" to mean "function". If it matters (to the explanation) that the function doesn't return a value, you can use "void function", but just using "void" is confusing.

Comment: Try taking a look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr and take a look at the vector container https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector to replace arrays.

Comment: @TripeHound I have to use void, it is stated in the assignment like this

Comment: @EmreOz I was talking about the text of the question: "I'm trying to print a value found in the "getvalue" _function_ in the "show" _function_" is clearer (IMHO) than using "void" as you did. I wasn't suggesting the functions shouldn't (continue to) return `void`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the value.

It can be done via reference:

```
// omit

void getValue(Student*& Students) // add reference argument
{
    cout << "Enter the number of students: ";
    cin >> studentNumber;
    cout << "Enter the number of tests: ";
    cin >> testNumber;

    // don't declare here and use the arugment
    Students = new Student[studentNumber];

    // omit
}

void show(Student* Students) // add argument (need not be reference)
{
    // omit
}

int main()
{
    // add variable for arguments and use that
    Student* s;
    getValue(s);
    show(s);
}
```

Or via global variable:

```
// omit

// declare variable here (as global)
static Student* Students;

void getValue()
{
    cout << "Enter the number of students: ";
    cin >> studentNumber;
    cout << "Enter the number of tests: ";
    cin >> testNumber;

    // don't declare here and use the global variable
    Students = new Student[studentNumber];

    // omit
}

void show()
{
    // omit
}

int main()
{
    getValue();
    show();
}
```

Comment: *Neither* of these are good solutions in most cases …

Comment: Also, your code has no hint of clean-up after use: `delete[] s;` in your (first) `main` would be trivial but then there's the matter of the allocated `testResults` arrays in each `Student` - adding a destructor would be good for that!

Comment: I tried the "global variable" solution but it returned the error "Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)"

Comment: @AdrianMole I still have functions like average calculation I need to do. I'll do delete last.

Comment: @EmreOz The solution [worked for me](https://wandbox.org/permlink/XQ1myc1gEdgeJgde). Didn't you forget to remove the declaration of local `Students`?

Comment: @MikeCAT "Students = new Student [studentNumber];" I deleted line and "static Student * Students;" I added this line

Comment: The allocation and assignment must be retained

Comment: @MikeCAT I did like the link, thank you "static Student * Students;" instead of "Student * Students;" I have to write

Answer (score 0):

Instead of raw arrays, it might be good to use `std::vector<Student>`. It'd be easy to replace:

```
    Student* Students = new Student[studentNumber];
```

with:

```
#include <vector>
...
    std::vector<Student> Students(studentNumber);
```

(pretty much everything else should be the same) and then for the actual error you're seeing, since the `Students` array only exists inside the scope of the `getValue()` function, you'll need to `return` it so that `show()` can the array too. Consider changing the code to something like (assuming you're using the vector):

```
std::vector<Student> getValue() {
    ...
    return Students;
}
void show(std::vector<Student> Students)
    ...
}
int main() {
    auto Students = getValue();
    show(Students);
}
```

Comment: The code works like this but we didn't see "vector" in our lessons. I don't know if I can use it.